# JTree set handle visible on first node level when root is not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree like this:

```
MasterRoot
+-RootA
 +-ChildA1
  +-GrandChildA1a
+-RootB
 +-ChildB1
  +-GrandChildB1a
```

I don't want the MasterRoot node to be displayed
But if I call `configTree.setRootVisible(false);

I got:

```
RootA
 +-ChildA1
  +-GrandChildA1a
RootB
 +-ChildB1
  +-GrandChildB1a
```

And I want this:

```
+-RootA
 +-ChildA1
  +-GrandChildA1a
+-RootB
 +-ChildB1
  +-GrandChildB1a
```

Note: yes I just need the '+-' (what the name for that ? Node Handler ??) to be displayed to my first level nodes after the master root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The '+-' is called a 'handle' and the method you need to call is `setShowsRootHandles(true)`.

This is really just a hint to the UI. It's left up to the look and feel whether to honor the hint.

Comment: Thanks a lot and all my apologies for being so late in accepting your answer.